# Returning JSON depending on the route_id

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller that has a purpose of returning json depending on the `route_id` being passed from the route (Using laravel). There's a point in my code where I resorted to using a double nested `foreach` loop in order to iterate the values I want to be stored into an array. Everything works fine, but I feel like the code is messy. Any tips?

```
public function getRoute($id)
{
    $route = Route_log::find($id);      
    $allWayPoints = explode(";", $route->route_order);
    $firstWaypoint = array_shift($allWayPoints); //get first waypoint

    foreach($allWayPoints as $allWayPoint)
        {
            $allOrdersInWaypoint = Transaction::where('waypoint_id', "=", $allWayPoint)->where('type', "=", "DD")->get()->lists('order_id');
            $allOrders[] = array($allOrdersInWaypoint);
        }
  ///**THIS PART**
    foreach($allOrders as $allOrder)
    {
        foreach($allOrder as $aO)
        {
            foreach($aO as $a)
            {
                $otherOrders = Order::find($a);

                if(isset($otherOrders))
                {
                $getOtherOrders[] = array(
                                            'id'             => $otherOrders->id,
                                            'tracking_id'    => $otherOrders->tracking_id,
                                            'shipper_ref_no' => $otherOrders->shipper_ref_no);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //get all transactions within the first way point
    $ordersInWaypoint = array();
    $ordersInWaypoint = Transaction::where('waypoint_id', "=", $firstWaypoint)->where('type', "=", "PP")->get()->lists('order_id');

    //get order id, tracking_id, and shipper ref no and store into an array
    foreach($ordersInWaypoint as $ordersInWaypoints)
        {
            $order = Order::find($ordersInWaypoints);

            //this array stores id, trackingId, and shipper_ref_no per order
            $getOrder[] = array(
                                'id'             => $order->id,
                                'tracking_id'    => $order->tracking_id,
                                'shipper_ref_no' => $order->shipper_ref_no);    
        }

    $json = (array('first_waypoint' => $getOrder, 'remaining_waypoints' => $getOtherOrders));

    return $json;
}

}
```

To show an example array inside `$allOrders`:

```
 array (size=20)
   0 => 
     array (size=1)
      0 => 
         array (size=2)
           0 => int 491
           1 => int 494
   1 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         array (size=0)
           empty
   2 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         array (size=1)
           0 => int 498
   3 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         array (size=2)
           0 => int 487
           1 => int 493
   4 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         array (size=1)
           0 => int 503
   5 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         array (size=1)
           0 => int 480
   6 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         array (size=1)
           0 => int 476
   7 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         array (size=1)
           0 => int 482
   8 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         array (size=1)
           0 => int 515
```

Comment: Are you constrained to the structure of `$allOrders` by some outside source?

Comment: @everlof Not at all. My goal there was to just get the data from another array.

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3.

Answer (score 1):

How about somethink like:

```
 $allOrders = array();
 foreach($allWayPoints as $allWayPoint)
 {
            $allOrdersInWaypoint = Transaction::where('waypoint_id', "=", $allWayPoint)->where('type', "=", "DD")->get()->lists('order_id');
 //           $allOrders[] = array($allOrdersInWaypoint);
            $allOrders = array_merge($allOrders, $allOrdersInWaypoint);
 }

 foreach($allOrders as $order)
 {
       $otherOrders = Order::find($order);

       if(isset($otherOrders))
       {
            $getOtherOrders[] = array(
                                            'id'             => $otherOrders->id,
                                            'tracking_id'    => $otherOrders->tracking_id,
                                            'shipper_ref_no' => $otherOrders->shipper_ref_no);
       }
 }
```

Then they wont be nested and `$allOrders` will simply be a flat array containing the numbers, assuming `$allOrdersInWaypoint` is a array of numbers.